# Shell output to a txt file using subprocess in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to make an output txtfile by using subprocess in Python 3.6 but the thing is that the documention does not really show me how to code in Windows. For instance,

```
import subprocess     
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does not work on my computer somehow and neither other examples. 
Could you kindly give me some hints to complete this code?

```
 f = open('output.txt', 'w')
 subprocess.check_output( ? , shell=True, ? )

 print("Example")
 print("Example")

 f.close()
```

Comment: A default Windows installation won't have an `ls` command. Try using `dir` which is available on the platform. You can find out more about what that command does by typing `help dir` in the shell.

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the replay :) I solved it right after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** make sure you use `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.Popen`

Windows differences aside (like martineau said in the comments to your OP, `ls` won't work on Windows, you need to use the `dir` command), you want to use `subprocess.PIPE` to be able to store the output of a command to a variable. Then you should be able to iterate through that variable, storing it in a file, something like:

```
# Save the output of the `dir` command
var = subprocess.run( <dir_command>, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# Iterate through the lines saved in `var`, and write them to `file`, line by line
with open('path/to/file', 'a') as file:
    for line in var:
         file.write(line)

file.close()
```